# Webpage: Button to check self (HTML page) and open the next HTML page alphabetically located in the same folder

Tags: javascript, html, button, alphabetical

Curious if by using javascript or the like, I can click a button and it would open the next alphabetically listed .htm page I have located in that same folder. I would try to use a naming convention, but the .htm files change quite frequently and their names can be random. The good news is there are not many files even at their greatest amount.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: The failure was such, that I did not find it beneficial to even post. I am basically looking for someone to get the metaphorical ball rolling on the solution. What that means is: I am looking for someone to write the code for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some more research to help show that I was attempting to solve this too, I found that this sort of local perspective scripting isn't safe and have therefore sought alternative remedies elsewhere. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

(It is help full asp.net user like me.Its may be help full for.)
I have an idia for you from which you can solved your problem. 
The all file's name store in list or dictionary as like you and also take  "static" variables name like "FileName" that is use for file name and  another like "CurrentIndex".But both variable are declared globally.When we click on button then increase current index and also manage the file name according to current index.

**If till now your problem is not solved out, please response me**